# How to print on console during MapReduce job execution in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to print each step of my "map" after its execution on the console.

Something like

System.out.println("Completed Step one");
System.out.println("Completed Step two");

and so on

Is there a special command to do that or is it not possible at all, as System.out.println doesn't seem to work at all ?

Please guide

Comment: you seemed to have asked quite a lot of questions lately but you dont seem to have the courtesy to accept an answer or at the very least upvote any of the provided answers. Pretty soon people will start ignoring you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `System.out.println(..`. To see whats been printed, open the jobtracker web console. Then navigate to your submitted job's link. On the Job page, you will see links to all your individual Map/Reduce tasks. Follow the links.. you will find a link that displays the dump  of both the Standard output as well as the Standard error.

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks for the answer and apologies if u found me rude. I did not respond to your last answer as I have not tried on it till now and had thought of coming back to it later. I am in a complete disastrous situation right now as my project deadline is on my head and I am facing loads of errors dats mainly because I never had ny form of hadoop training. sorry but never meant to be rude, nyways how do v upvote an answer.

Comment: oh.. im sorry i didnt realize you weren't aware. i wouldn't have been so critical. Anyway if you find some answer is useful, there is "0" with an up and down arrow on the left side of the answer. you can upvote by clicking on the up arrow (you can also downvote if you find the answer really unhelpfull). -or- If you feel the solution provided has properly answered your question, there is a tick mark on the side.. click that.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot upvote as I still do not have 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stdout yarn log to check the prints done with  System.out.println(). Check this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35526819/3998212