# How to see stuff printed during execution of hadoop job

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I am running a mapreduce job in HortonWorks virtualbox. In method `Map()`, I use `System.out.println("xx")` but I cannot find printed words.

From 
[How to print on console during MapReduce job execution in hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942670/how-to-print-on-console-during-mapreduce-job-execution-in-hadoop) I know that I can find log in jobtracker web console.
But I don't know where to find jobtracker web console.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That topic is for 4 years ago. JobTracker and TaskTracker (MRv1) have been transformed to Application Master and ResourceManager (MRv2:YARN). You can see your jobs status in ResourceManager web ui at `http://localhost:8088/`.

The output(From Reporter or Println) usually will be printed in task logs at HistoryServer which is available via this URL: `http://localhost:19888/jobhistory/job/job_xxxxxxxxxx`

PS: If you use an old version of hadoop, your output will be available via JobTracker web ui : `http://localhost:50030/jobtracker.jsp`(Click on the completed job->click on map or reduce task->click on tasknumber->task logs->stdout logs.)

Comment: Thank you Mobin, you helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Thank Mobin answering my question, let me add an answer to my question. 
Besides solution given by Mobin, I found another way to check logs of Hadoop job.
Command: `yarn logs -applicationId {applicationId}` can show logs of hadoop jobs saved in application history server including stderr, stdout and syslog. What printed by System.out.println() statement is saved in stdout.

Comment: I just wanted to add that you can use yarn logs -applicationId {applicationID} -log_files stdout to only view stdout log. Otherwise you will be checking the entire log.